# NCurses and Perl, any guides?

Tags: perl, ncurses

I need to use NCurses, with Perl. I found some very short bits of text about it but no example at all.

Is there anyone aware of any existing guide online?

Thanks!

Comment: Google searched "ncurses perl tutorial", found this:
http://search.cpan.org/~mdxi/Curses-UI-0.9607/lib/Curses/UI/Tutorial.pod

It looks like a good start, or is this what you already found?

Comment: Don't use "Google found this" next time. After 3 year, this very question is 2nd best result on Google on that phrase.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

http://metacpan.org/pod/Curses::UI::Tutorial

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

The examples from tldp.org are:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/ncurses_programs/perl/

Also, from http://www.perl.com/doc/FAQs/FAQ/oldfaq-html/Q3.8.html:

> For a good example of using curses
>   with Perl, you might want to pick up a
>   copy of Steven L Kunz's*  `perl
>   menus'' package (`menu.pl'') via
>   anonymous FTP from
>   ``ftp.iastate.edu''. It's in the
>   directory /pub/perl as:
>   menu.pl.v3.1.tar.Z
>
> Another possibility is to use Henk
>   Penning's cterm package, a curses
>   emulation library written in perl.
>   cterm is actually a separate program
>   with which you communicate via a pipe.
>   It is available from ftp.cs.ruu.nl
>   [131.211.80.17] via anonymous ftp. in
>   the directory pub/PERL.

Comment: This link is broken: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/ncurses_programs/perl/