# How would I move the cursor back of one position in a terminal?

Tags: perl, text-cursor

I want to show an animation that alternate the character `/`, `|` and `\`.

How am I supposed to write always in the same cell of the terminal? I need to bring the cursor back of one position.

Comment: I suggest you check [ncurses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907321/ncurses-and-perl-any-guides) library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most terminals will handle a backspace (`chr(8)`) by moving the cursor back. The key is to disable buffering.

```
use Time::HiRes qw( sleep );

$| = 1;  # Disable buffering on STDOUT.

my $BACKSPACE = chr(0x08);

my @seq = qw( | / - \ );
for (;;) {
   print $seq[0];
   push @seq, shift @seq;
   sleep 0.200;
   print $BACKSPACE;
}

print "$BACKSPACE $BACKSPACE";
```

Comment: Kids don't do this at home! `print(chr 0x08,(qw(\ | / -))[$i++%4])&&select'','','',0.2 while++$|`

Answer (score 2):

An variant of ikegami's answer :)

```
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);
$| = 1;  # Disable buffering on STDOUT ;)

for(1..10) {
    for (qw( | / - \ )) {
        print "$_\b";
        sleep 0.2;
    }
}
print
```

Comment: I wrote mine so it would be easy to integrate into other code.

Comment: ofc, your solution is "better". Only the push - splice (voodoo rotating) is not obvious in the 1st read. ;)

Comment: btw, why not? push @seq, shift @seq;

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you output things in perl, but this is generally accomplished by outputting the backspace character \b (ASCII code 8). In C++, for example, this is done by outputting char(8).