# Multiple Updating Lines in Perl

Tags: perl, command, refresh, lines, backspace

The output I'm trying to accomplish is something along the lines of:

```
     line1 = get
     line2 = shwifty
     line3 = in
     line4 = here
```

...and in the command-line be refreshing all of those strings without continuously reposting new lines! I can get this working a few ways IF ONLY ONE LINE IS USED but how would I write over or backspace past MULTIPLE lines??

Right now, the command prompt will yield:

```
     line1 = get
     line2 = shwifty
     line3 = in
     line4 = here
     line1 = get2
     line2 = shwifty2
     line3 = in2
     line4 = here2
```

how can I just "refresh" the four lines that I want?

Comment: You could use [NCurses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907321/ncurses-and-perl-any-guides) or write [ANSI codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) if your terminal supports it (they likely do).

Answer (score 1):

For multiple lines, the `tput` command is helpful. A demo:

```
clear
for ((i=1; i<=4; i++)); do 
    tput cup 0 0
    printf "%s$i\n" get shwifty in here
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Oops, not perl code. Well, `qx{tput ...}` or there's bound to be a module